# How to Save ng-repeat $index to DB ( rownumber: 1.1 ,1.2,1.3) using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on index page of book functionality

```
i.e : 1.1
        1.1.1
      1.2
        1.2.1
```

where  1.1 & 1.2 is parent ng-repeat  &
 1.1.1 & 1.1.2 is child ng-reapet

now i want to save this number(ng-reapet indexces) to my database for reference. like 1.1 number task !!

that all raw has update delete functionality as well so how do i do it on cilck like saveAllIndex button click.

```
 <li ng-repeat ="title in projectStructure" >
    <span class="pull-left m-r-sm"> {{$index+1}}</span>
    <div class="clear" ng-if="!title.enableEdit"  >{{title.title}} 

  <li ng-repeat ="subTitle in title.subTitles" class="list-group-item">
    <span class="pull-left m-r-sm">{{$parent.$index+1}}.{{$index+1}}</span>
    <div class="clear" ng-if="!subTitle.enableEdit"  >{{subTitle.childrensTitle}}

   <li ng-repeat ="subContentTitle in subTitle.subTitles" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="pull-left m-r-sm">    
            {{$parent.$parent.$index+1}}.{{$parent.$index+1}}.{{$index+1}}</span>
        <div class="clear" ng-if="!subContentTitle.enableEdit">     
             {{subContentTitle.childrensTitle}}

     <button class="btn btn-success m-l-xl " ng-click="addSubChild(?)" >saveAllNgRepeatIndex</button>
```

Comment: how many repeat are you using?, you need three levels in your html view

Comment: I'm using 4 level so i have kept 4 ng-repeat !!  like from 1,   1.1 ,  1.1.1,  1.1.1.1

Comment: you can use ng-init to define default model value like this {{$parent.$parent.$index}}.{{$parent.$index}}.{{$index}}, this a demo of would be .

Comment: to display 1.1 & 1.1.1 n so on i have used {{$index}},{{ $parent.$index}} , {{$parent.$parent.$index }}. now i want to save that to db. each row is unique!

Comment: ok you need inverse counter, ok, then using ng-init you cand default define model of data as you want

Comment: can you please brief about it ? let say i have 10 items in first ng-repeat n 15 in second ng-repeat so how do we get total 25 indexes on single click n how we save it !  it seems quite tedious isn't it ?

Comment: ng-repeat="your repeat" ng-init="datavalue={{$index}},{{ $parent.$index}} , {{$parent.$parent.$index }}" data-db="{{datavalue}}"></

Comment: i am using Mean Stack framework i have to make http request to dig db n save it. will it work over there ?

Comment: you can use $scope.datavalue, but for all code you need to put here for help you

Comment: i have edited post it will be more clear hope so :)

Answer (score 0):

here is my idea of would be done:

```
<li ng-repeat ="title in projectStructure" >
    <span class="pull-left m-r-sm"  data-ng-init="title.dataValue="{{$index+1}}"> {{$index+1}}</span>
    <div class="clear" ng-if="!title.enableEdit"  >{{title.title}} 

  <li ng-repeat ="subTitle in title.subTitles" class="list-group-item">
    <span class="pull-left m-r-sm" data-ng-init="subTitle.dataValue="{{$parent.$index+1}}.{{$index+1}}">{{$parent.$index+1}}.{{$index+1}}</span>
    <div class="clear" ng-if="!subTitle.enableEdit"  >{{subTitle.childrensTitle}}

   <li ng-repeat ="subContentTitle in subTitle.subTitles" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="pull-left m-r-sm"   data-ng-init="subContentTitle.dataValue="{{$parent.$parent.$index+1}}.{{$parent.$index+1}}.{{$index+1}}">    
            {{$parent.$parent.$index+1}}.{{$parent.$index+1}}.{{$index+1}}</span>
        <div class="clear" ng-if="!subContentTitle.enableEdit">     
             {{subContentTitle.childrensTitle}}

     <button class="btn btn-success m-l-xl " ng-click="addSubChild(?)" >saveAllNgRepeatIndex</button>
```

Then you can access to the node "dataValue", at the object original repeated.

thanks

Comment: Thank you for your effort ! learnt something new  ! but not the right solution for problem !